# Fetched Date is setting incorrectly

Tags: java, spring

So for example I save `Date` to database:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date arrivalDate;
```

And it is saved to database as this date for example `2021-09-01`. Then I fetch this date and add two day for example and it should be `2021-09-03`. This is the code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(r.getArrivalDate()); // 2021-09-01
c.add(Calendar.DATE, r.getLivedFor()); // +2 days
residencesReportLine.setDepartDate(c.getTime());
```

But the result I get is not the correct I want, because I get this:

```
arrivalDate: 2021-08-31
departDate: 2021-09-02
```

is should be

```
arrivalDate: 2021-09-01
departDate: 2021-09-03
```

How I should fix this?

Comment: `@JsonFormat` drives formatting only if serializing to JSON, not to a DB.  Your specific database engine will determine how dates are stored.  Not sure why your dates are off, but it's probably a time zone thing.  I would also suggest using the newer `java.time` stuff as opposed to the old `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` stuff as the newer is much cleaner to interact with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy--MM-dd")
private Date arrivalDate;


SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(r.getArrivalDate());
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
residencesReportLine.setDepartDate(Timestamp.valueOf(output));
```